# Finding unkown point (x,y) given 2 points and distance in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, math, algebra

i just get to the point and describe my problem  .
Given a square **not** parallel  to the axis !

i have (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and  the distance beetween them dx(width/height of the square)
i need to find  the point (x,y) describe in the photo 
(cant upload photo)
link to the image : [the problem photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fiii76u19u084sf/IMG_20140902_130904.jpg?dl=0)

first i tried the equation (x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = dx^2 
                            (x-x2(^2 + (y-y2)^2 = 2 dx^2 
but i cant manage to solve this equation when i try to code it ,

anyone have any idea's how to solve the problem in code or another equation or solution to find the point ?.

*i using c# 4,0

Comment: "but i cant manage to solve this equation when i try to code it" why is that so? please elaborate! show us some code and the point out the line, which troubles you!

Comment: In your image, what is the distance between (x,y) and (x1,y1)? The same as between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)?

Comment: or, to be more specific, is what you have drawn supposed to be a circle?

Comment: It's not possible, you just can draw a radius where the point could be. Because there is no given relation between dx and dy, but you need some restictions like dy = 1/2dx to calculate the point you're searching for

Comment: And it's impossible to find a specific (x,y) point because only with three data, (two points and the distance between these two) you can draw a circle that has inifinite points

Comment: it a **square** the distance between (x,y) and (x1,y1) equals to the distance between  (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) the distance is some real that mines that dx = dy !

i realize the problem is mathematic but when i try code i cant manage to isolate the x or the y because the unkown.

Comment: How to solve, yes. Hint: Use trigonometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple.

```
var dx = x2 - x1;
var dy = y2 - y1;

var rotatedDx = dy;
var rotatedDy = -dx;

x = x1 + rotatedDx;
y = y1 + rotatedDy;
```

Basically, you compute vector P1 -> P2 and rotate it by 90 degrees.

Comment: Exactly. Given a vector `(x,y)`, the vector `(y,-x)` is perpendicular and of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using complex numbers by representing the points on an Argand diagram. (I think)

Since its a square, the sides are equal and 90degrees apart you can do this. (Refer to dropbox picture)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymimimgkuzhkcub/IMAG3818.jpg?dl=0

A is point (x1, y1) with value x1 + (y1)i
B is x2 + (y2)i
P and Q are the locations of the 2 possible places (x, y) can be and they are x + yi. Solve the 2 equation in the picture for values of x and y.

Comment: Opps I think I was thinking way too complex >< Refer to Vlad's solution.